# Convergence of non-negative $(a_n)^p$ series if the series $a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to prove the following:

Suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers and that the series $\sum a_n$ converges. Prove that the series $\sum a_n^p$ converges for p>1.

How should I start this prove? Should I break down $a_n$ into three cases: $a_n$ equals 1, less then 1, greater than 1? or Should I use comparison test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you already gave the answer in your question.

If $\sum a_n$ converges, $\{a_n\}$ converges to zero. As we’re dealing with non negative series and $p \gt 1$, we have for all $n $ large enough

$$0\le a_n^p \le a_n$$ and therefore $\sum a_n^p$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

There exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;n>N\implies a_n<1\implies a_n^p<a_n\;$ for $\;p>1\;$ ...